# HtmlAgilityPack select data from sub-node

Tags: c#, html, linq, parsing, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML code I'd like to parse:

```
<h3 class='bar'>
  <a href='http://anysite.com/index.php?showuser=7195' title='Profile view'>THIS_IS_USERNAME</a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href='http://anysite.com/index.php?showuser=7195&amp;f=' class='__user __id7195' title='Profile view'>
      <img src='http://anysite.com/public/style_images/car/user_popup.png' alt='' />
   </a>
</h3>
```

What I need here is to select username ("THIS_IS_USERNAME") and the link to the profile ("http://anysite.com/index.php?showuser=7195")

I can select the top h3 node using the next code:

```
List<HtmlNode> resultSearch = HTMLPage.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(
                         x => x.Name.Equals("h3")
                         && x.Attributes["class"] != null
                         && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Equals("bar")                         
                      )
                .ToList();
```

But how can I get not the "h3" node itself, but "a" inside "h3" with this attributes link that contains username and the link to profile which I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for the link node directly, it's pretty distinctive with the Title attribute on it.

In this case using an XPath is probably simpler as it handles all the intermediate null checks and it's just as type-safe, since your Linq query will have a lot of constant strings:

```
var node = HTMLPage.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//hr[@class='Bar']/a[@title='Profile View' and @href");
if (node != null)
{
    string link = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
    string username = node.InnerText;
}
```

You can write similar code using the Linq syntax, it first searches the link tag and then backtracks to find a h3 parent for it. That way you don't have to check for intermediate nulls ;):

```
var node = HtmlPage.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
    .Where(a =>
        a.Ascendants("h3")
            .Any(h3 =>
                h3.Attributes["class"] != null 
                && a.Attributes["class"].Value == "bar"
            )
    )
    .Where(a => 
        a.Attributes["title"] != null 
        && a.Attributes["title"].Value == "Profile View"
        && a.Attributes["href"] != null
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (node != null)
{
    string link = node.Attributes["href"].value;
    string username = node.InnerText;
}
```

Or you can use the position of it being the first `<a>` child of "bar":

```
// the call to First() will throw an exception if the h3 isn't found.
// returning an empty HtmlNode will allow you to ignore that

var node = (HtmlPage.DocumentNode.Descendants("h3")
    .FirstOrDefault( h => 
            h3.Attributes["class"] != null 
            && a.Attributes["class"].Value == "bar")
    ) ?? HtmlPage.CreateElement("h3")) 
    .Elements("a").FirstOrDefault();

if (node != null)
{
    string link = node.Attributes["href"].value;
    string username = node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exaclty what I was looking for!

Comment: Though the last part with new HtmlNode("h3"))
    .Elements("a").FirstOrDefault();
 is a bit unclear, seems not to be working